# html page doesn't fit screen

Tags: html, css, size

I'm trying to make my page feet the screen, but I found that a scroll bar always appear, I'm using `vh` and `vw` to try and make it, so it always displays the page without scroll bars. I think the problem is some type of padding, but I'm not sure, how can I make sure that the page is the size of the screen?

```css
   body {    
        margin: 0;
    }
    
    #container {    
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    header {    
        height: 25vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: #CCC;
        text-align: center;        
    }
    
    header img {    
        height: 20vh;
        width: : 50vw;
    }
        
    aside {    
        width: 20vw;
        height:  80vh;
        background-color: #0C0;
        float: right;    
    }
    
    aside ul {    
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    aside li {    
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    aside li a {    
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 5vh;
    }
    
    aside li a:hover {    
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
    
    main {    
        width: 80vw;
        height: 80vh;
        background-color: #03C;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    footer {    
        height: 5vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: #CCC;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    /*Menu*/
    nav {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 5vh;
        background-color: #666;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul {    
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    nav li {    
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;    
    }
    
    nav li a {
        height: 3vh;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 1vh 8vw;
    }
    
    nav li a:hover {    
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
```

```html
    
      <div id="container">
      <header><img src="imatges/Gwlogo.png" alt="Mountain View"</header>
      <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Formulari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Iframe</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
    
      <aside>
    
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Formulari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Iframe</a></li>
       </ul>
       
      </aside>
      <main></main>
      <footer></footer>
      </div>
```

Comment: you need to share full code

Comment: Share some HTML code.

Comment: Added the HTML part!

Comment: can you create a fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: seems to work (using firefox): https://jsfiddle.net/oj5yfmef/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/werf5v9w/ here's the link, it's the first time that i use the page, seems very useful!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the net height of all the elements was more then 100vh. so you need to change that and also define `max-height:100vh;` on body, html

```css
   body {    
        margin: 0;
     height:100vh;
     width:100%;
     max-width:100vh;
    }
    
    #container {    
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
    }
    
    header {    
        height: 20vh;
        width: 100vw;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
        background-color: #CCC;
        text-align: center;        
    }
    
    header img {    
        height: 20vh;
        //width: 50vw;
      margin:0 auto;
      padding:0;
      display:block;
    }
        
    aside {    
        width: 20vw;
        height:  70vh;
      
        background-color: #0C0;
        float: right;    
    }
    
    aside ul {    
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    aside li {    
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    aside li a {    
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        height: 5vh;
    }
    
    aside li a:hover {    
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
    
    main {    
        width: 80vw;
        height: 70vh;
        background-color: #03C;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    footer {    
        height: 5vh;
        width: 100vw;
        background-color: #CCC;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    /*Menu*/
    nav {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 5vh;
        background-color: #666;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul {    
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    nav li {    
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;    
    }
    
    nav li a {
        height: 3vh;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 1vh 8vw;
    }
    
    nav li a:hover {    
        background-color: #CCC;
    }
```

```html
      <div id="container">
      <header><img src="http://www.chinabuddhismencyclopedia.com/en/images/thumb/b/b8/Nature.jpg/240px-Nature.jpg" alt="Mountain View"</header>
      <nav>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Formulari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Iframe</a></li>
       </ul>
      </nav>
    
      <aside>
    
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calendari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Formulari</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Iframe</a></li>
       </ul>
       
      </aside>
      <main></main>
      <footer></footer>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, you were right about the height of the elements, but why do i need to use max-height?

Comment: It's just a precaution. if you ever forget to set `margin:0;` on any element.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna main scroll bar disappear, add css properties `overflow: hidden;` in your `body` or `html` tag.

> how can i make sure that the page is the size of the screen?

if the page you mean is body or html, set the padding, border, and margin to 0 just to make sure it's fit to the size of screen, but if you mean the page is `div` with `id='container'` try this

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

it will fit the screen